# Display website in browser after submitting a form using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize

I'm looking to use Python (working in 2.7) to:

1. Open a website (specifically http://nunuku.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/getcssconedb_release_img.cgi).
2. Input form data on that page based on strings the Python script finds on my local machine.
3. Display the resulting page in the browser.

I was initially looking at using mechanize, which works fine for parts (1) and (2). However, with mechanize one gets the resulting page's HTML as output (`content` in the code below). I can then write that HTML to a local file and open it using `webbrowser.open()`, but since the resulting page has javascript, things don't display properly (and what's not displaying is more-or-less the whole point of looking at this page in the first place).

Is there any way to do part (3)? The cheap trick would be to use `webbrowser.open()` with the final URL string (and my local data inserted), except that the URL doesn't change at all once "Submit" is pressed.

Relevant code, as it stands (includes saving the HTML to the local machine and opening it that way):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import webbrowser
import mechanize

url = 'http://nunuku.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/getcssconedb_release_img.cgi'
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr = 0)
br['RA'] = ra
br['Dec'] = dec
br['Rad'] = '0.1'
br['IMG'] = ['nun']    # These are for the radio buttons.
br['DB'] = ['photcat']
br['OUT'] = ['csv']
br['SHORT'] = ['short']
response = br.submit()
content = response.read()
with open('results.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(content)
webbrowser.open('results.html')
```

(In the above, the `br[]` statements are the form labels on the page, and the `ra` and `dec` variables are values taken from my files depending on the situation. E.g., `ra = 03:50:10.71` and `dec = +32:32:29.60`. You could plug those into the site--if you're so inclined--to see what I'm trying to see.)

Any and all advice is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see You are intrested in displaying page with values 
not just getting the data for sent request.
Your's idea isn't bad, but mechanize as You see isn't using any of actual Browser instance. Mechanize is

> programmatic web browsing

And I'm guessing you are looking for something like :

> [Python-Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)

Comment: This was absolutely the way to go. Thanks a ton!